# dpkg: error processing package dradis

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I just ran `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` and this is what I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up dradis (3.1.0~rc2+git20160609-0kali2) ...
Warning: The home dir /var/lib/dradis you specified already exists.
The system user `dradis' already exists. Exiting.
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:194:in `block in initialize': 
    undefined method `add_root_vertex' for Molinillo::DependencyGraph:[]:Molinillo::DependencyGraph (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:194:in `initialize'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:181:in `new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:181:in `resolve'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:200:in `resolve'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:140:in `specs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:185:in `specs_for'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:174:in `requested_specs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:127:in `setup'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/setup.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /usr/lib/dradis/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rake:2:in `require_relative'
    from bin/rake:2:in `<main>'
dpkg: error processing package dradis (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 dradis
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What should I do?

Comment: Looks like a missing dependency. `/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:194:in 'block in initialize': undefined method 'add_root_vertex' for Molinillo::DependencyGraph:[]:Molinillo::DependencyGraph (NoMethodError)`

Comment: so what should i do now? any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

`deb` packages have some hooks defined, where scripts can be executed while the package is installed, uninstalled etc. It seems that in your case one such script fails, so the whole installation fails:

```
 /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/resolver.rb:194:in `block in initialize': 
    undefined method `add_root_vertex' for Molinillo::DependencyGraph:[]:Molinillo::DependencyGraph (NoMethodError)
```

So [Bundler](http://bundler.io/) can't find a method in a library it would like to call. Judging from [this issue](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4383) at Bundler's Github repo, you might be using an outdated version of Bundler. So maybe upgrading Bundler would help. How exactly you need to do that depends on how you installed Ruby including Bundler (package system, RVM, rbenv, ...)

Comment: i did not install ruby seperately i guess it got installed the last time i did apt-get update && apt-get upgrade... n is there any way to solve this .. coz the last option i have is to reinstall the os

Comment: Look which version of ruby you're using at the moment: `bundler -v`. Look whether it's the most current: `gem list -r ^bundler$`.  The same way, check whether the [molinillo](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Molinillo) is at the most current version:  `gem list -l molinillo` and `gem list -r molinillo`.  Those two are the ones that need to "interact" in your case, but it fails.

Comment: You can upgrade a Gem with `gem update name-of-the-gem`. But be aware that something else might not be compatible with the newer version then, so no guarantees ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help.. but i just reinstalled the os n then did an update.. n everything works fine now.. ...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in Kali. Removing dradis fixed it for me.

```
apt-get remove dradis
```